# MySQl update column with values in a specific format

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am working on an old application and mysql db that is sadly all in a bit of a mess.

I am interested in a column needed for export that contains names of editors for particular documents. The values in this column should be formatted in a particular way, and should be consistent which they are currently not.

A document can have many editors. I have a table containing all distinct editors which I need to seomhow match against the current (incorrectly formatted) editors value. I know this is not the best way to go about doing this (it is how the application currently works) but I need the editors column to be formatted as follows:

```
"Surname, Initial. and Surname, Initial. and Surname, Initial"
```

E.g.:

```
"Bloggs, J. and Doe, J."
"Smith, M.J. and Bloggs, J. and Jones, P"
"Williams, S. and Smith, M.J. Doe, J."
```

However the column is currently inconsistent with no real formatting in place:

```
"J Bloggs, J Doe"
"MJ Smith, J Bloggs and P Jones"
"Williams, S, M.J Smith. Doe, J."
```

etc...

Here are my current tables:

**Documents**:

```
| title       |  editors                       |
------------------------------------------------
| doc title 1 |  J Bloggs, J Doe               |
| doc title 2 |  M Smith, J Bloggs and P Jones |
| doc title 3 |  Williams, S, M Smith. Doe, J. |
```

**Eitors**:

```
| initial | name       |
------------------------
| J.      | Bloggs     |
| J.      | Doe        |
| M.J.    | Smith      |
| P.      | Jones      |
| S.      | Williams   |
```

For testing purposes I have added a column (formatted_editors) to the Documents table:

```
| title       |  editors                       | formatted_editors              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which I need to look something like this:

```
| title       |  editors                       | formatted_editors              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| doc title 1 |  J Bloggs, J Doe               | Bloggs, J. and Doe, J.
| doc title 2 |  M Smith, J Bloggs and P Jones | Smith, M.J. and Bloggs, J. and Jones, P
| doc title 3 |  Williams, S, M Smith. Doe, J. | Williams, S. and Smith, M.J. Doe, J.
```

---

I have tried the following (and various others) but cant seem to have any luck - I think it may have something to do with my groupings ?

```
SELECT d. title, d.editors, group_concat(e.name, ', ', e.initial SEPARATOR ' and ') as      formatted_editors 
FROM documents d
INNER JOIN editors e
ON d.editors LIKE concat('%', e.name, '%')
WHERE d.editors LIKE concat('%', e.name, '%') 
and  et.editors LIKE concat('%', e.initial, '%')
GROUP BY et.editors;
```

Any help / pointers would be appreciated,

Comment: Why do editors have ids if they're referenced by name?

Comment: I think you are in deep trouble. looks like manual entry in the `editors` field. If you want it to be correct, you may have to manually go through each record and edit it (how big is your table?). how are you going to make out that `M Smith.` refers to `Smith, M.J.`? Also if there is a 'typo' somewhere what action to take?

Comment: @strawberry - sorry was just an example I threw together, I have now updated it !

Comment: @bansi I thought this would be the case ... although was hoping it was not :)

Comment: I'm with bansi. Given the variable nature of the input, this task is nigh on impossible without some application level code (and pretty difficult even then!) But if you're going to go to the trouble of cleaning this up manually, then you should use that time to properly normalize your data.

Answer (score 0):

No "real" reliable way to solve this then... I used some basic SQL to fix up / match what I can and did the rest manually.

Thanks,
Jon.